# How to convert an array to an object with a corresponding sub-sequent value?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, reduce

I am trying convert an array: `filterArrays([1, 2, true, true, false, '1', 'a', 3, {}, null, undefined])`
following pattern

```
{
    "number": [
        1,
        2,
        3
    ],
    "boolean": [
        true,
        true,
        false
    ],
    "string": [
        "1",
        "a"
    ],
    "object": [
        {},
        null
    ],
    "undefined": [
        null
    ]
}
```

Here is my try: which is working as expected value, Is there a better way to solve this problem?
Thanks;

```
const filterArrays = (values) => {
  return values.reduce((acc, obj) => {
        const key = typeof obj;
        if(acc[key]) {
            acc[key].push(obj)
        }
        else {
            acc[key] = [obj]
        }
        return acc;
  }, {});
}
```

Comment: as long as you want to categorize null and arrays also as objects seems fine

Comment: Your solution is good enough! If you want you can use ternary operator instead of if/else clause. like this : `acc[key] ? acc[key].push(obj) : acc[key] = [obj]`